# Entity framework code first. How to add a list of an object type file to an object that already has a property of that type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Have an object **Journal**.
Journal has a **Company** field.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Company")]
public int CompanyID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CompanyID")]
public Company Company { get; set; }
```

Company has a list of Journals

```
  public IList<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
```

Now couple of months after the project went live, there is a request for a **Journal** to have a possibility to have multiple **Companies** assigned to it.

Simple solution would be to just change the object field into:

```
 public IList<Company> Companies { get; set; }
```

mapped in the many to many table between Journals and Companies but as stated at the start, project and the database is live in production. The only solution I see is adding list of companies (multiCompanies) field on top of the **Company** field.

No idea how to to it in Entity though.

Comment: And how are you intending to fill that list of companies if you are not planning to reflect the changes in the database?

Comment: Hi. Changes of course will reflect the database.

Comment: Alright then - have you considered adding a joining/mapping table then to normalize the M:M relationship into 2x 1:M relationships. So you would have an extra table CompanyJournals where all the many to many mappings would be held and Company/Journals tables would have a 1:M with CompanyJournals.

Comment: How would you go about doing it with EF

Answer (score 1):

So original situation:
 - Company-Journal is one-to-many relation.
 - Every Company has zero or more Journals,
 - every Journal belongs to exactly one Company

Desired situation:
 - Company- Journal is a many-to-many relation
 - Every Company has zero or more Journals
 - Every Journal has zero or more Companies.

Many to many relations are usually done using a junction table. In entity framework classes you won't need this junction table. In your queries you'll use the ICollections:

```
class Company
{
    public int Id {get; set;}   // primary key

    // every Company has zero or more Journals
    public virtual ICollection<Journal> Journals {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
class Journal
{
    public int Id {get; set;}   // primary key

    // every Journal is used by zero or more Companies
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies{get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
```

If you want to change the configuration of an existing entity framework configured database you'll need to implement a migration. [See Entity Framework Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

What you'll have to do in the migration:

(1) Create a junction table Company_Journals
Two fields:
  (a) int CompanyId, required, foreign key to Company
  (b) int JournalId, required, foreign key to Journal

The combination of these two fields will be the primary key
See [CreateTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.createtable(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
class AddCompanyJournalsTable: DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable("dbo.Company_Journals",
        c => new
        {
            CompanyId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true)
            JournalId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true)
        });
```

The return value of a CreateTable is a T[ableBuilder object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829286(v=vs.113).aspx) which can be used to define the primary and foreign keys

```
.PrimaryKey(t => new {t.CompanyId, t.JournalId})
.ForeignKey("dbo.Companies", t => t.CompanyId, cascadeDelete: false)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Journals", t => t.JournalId, cascadeDelete: false)
```

(2) For every Journal you had in the previous version create one Company_Journal
pointing to the company and the journal:

```
IQueryable<Journal> allJournals = ...
foreach (Journal journal in allJournals)
{
    dbContext.Journals.Add(new Journal()
    {
        JournalId = journal.Id, // or whatever primary key you have in Journal
        CompanyId = journal.CompanyId
    });
}
```

(3) Remove the Journal.CompanyId using [DropColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.dropcolumn(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and approach this problem with a mapping table to normalize your new requirement which is causing the relationship between two tables to become M:M. Below is the example of how it could look like in EF.

```
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyJournals> CompanyJournals { get; set; }
    }

    public class Journal
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyJournals> CompanyJournals { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyJournals
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public int JournalId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("JournalId")]
        public virtual Journal Journal { get; set; }
    }
```